# "Could you tell me why you applied for this job?" or "Could you tell me why did you apply for this job?"

Tags: grammar

Choose the correct answer :

> Could you tell me why (**you applied** / **did you apply**) for this job?

personally , i would go for **"did you apply"**

however my textbook's answer is **"you applied"**

and it would be nice if someone can explain the difference between them

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase is not a question so doesn't have question order.

Compare a question:

> What is this?

with the request

> Tell me what this is.

The phrase "what this is" isn't a question clause. It is a noun phrase.  In your example the question

> Why did you apply for this job?

is compared to the request

> Tell me why you applied for this job.